# How to download files from URL in Flutter and save them in iOS shared Folder?

Tags: ios, flutter

Im pretty new to Flutter and I need a solution for the following steps:

1. Download a zip from an url
2. Extract the zip
3. Save the files to a shared folder in the application (iOS)
4. Remove the downloaded file from downloads

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a a package that will manage downloads for you called `flutter_downloader`: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader

There is another package that allows you to compress and decompress files called `archive`: https://pub.dev/packages/archive